# Error installing tensorflow on python 3.11

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to import tensorflow but I'm not capable to install it since when I run

```
pip install tensorflow
```

it shows

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I think the problem is that tensorflow runs in python < 3.11 versions. But I'm not sure. I've been looking for a solution using a virtual enviroment with python 3.10, but it seems pretty complicated for a noob like me. Thanks in advance

Comment: pip install tensorflow==2.11.0

Comment: nop, that's doesn't work: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.11.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.11.0

Comment: which os you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try alternative methods

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

If you want to build TensorFlow from source check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using Windows... I've opted for downloading the 3.9 version of python and adapting my code to that... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem but I got tensorflow to install by installing on python 3.10.9
[Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3109/)

Then adding those directories to my PATH and moving them to top priority.
[image of my PATH environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilMs6.png)

Confirm Python version number in Command Prompt

```
python --version
Python 3.10.9
```

Install tensorflow

```
python.exe -m pip install tensorflow
```

Hope that helps!